# Can I use Volt engine with another framework?

Tags: phalcon, volt

I'm developing a system (in Phalcon initially) for a project that will be delivered to many shared hosts. But unfortunately they only accept mainstream php frameworks (you cannot install extensions such as Phalcon).

This being said, I had to change framerwork for this project. But alot of stuff were already made using Volt template engine.

There is a way to use it with another frameworks? Or Volt is deeply wattled into Phalcon's core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like Volt can be decoupled from Phalcon entirely.
You could fall back on the Twig templating engine which seems to be the closest match language wise as well as completely standalone.

Comment: Please, don't use link only answers, expand on your answer please.